# How do you dynamically hide lightning:helptext popover elements?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, slds, helptext

The popover element (`lightning-primitive-bubble`) from a `lightning:helptext` component stays rendered on the page even after the parent component containing the `lightning:helptext` is destroyed and even if the `lightning:helptext` component is destroyed directly. This only happens on iOS devices. The popover disappears as expected on other platforms.

Is there a programmatic way of forcing the popover element to close?

EDIT: Including code that replicates the problem. These components are used inside a Lightning Community.

*HelptextTestParent.cmp*

```
<div class="slds-grid slds-grid_align-end">
    <div class="slds-col">
        <c:HelptextTestChild />
    </div>
</div>

<hr />
<br />

<div class="slds-grid">
    <div class="slds-col">
        <lightning:button
            variant="brand"
            label="Navigate"
            onclick="{!c.handleNavigate}"
        />
    </div>
</div>
```

*HelptextTestParentController.cmp*

```
({
    handleNavigate : function(component, event, helper) {
        $A.get('e.force:navigateToURL').setParams({
            url: '/navigate-to-url-test',
        }).fire();
    }
})
```

*HelptextTestChild.cmp*

```
<aura:component>
    <lightning:helptext content="I stay on screen on iOS devices" />
</aura:component>
```

Comment: please share the code where you are creating and destroying the components

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This resulted in a case with Salesforce. They have acknowledged this as a known limitation for iOS devices in the `lightning:helptext` [component documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:helptext/documentation) by explicitly stating helptext popovers must be closed by tapping on the popover.

> On iOS devices, the helptext popover opens when you tap on the icon and closes with a second tap on the popover or the icon.